# Python: regex parse text to create dict

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem with one task:

I have output from cisco hw.

```
IP access list 100  
        10 permit igmp any any  
        20 deny any any  
IP access list 200  
        10 permit ip 192.168.1.1/32   
        20 permit ip 192.168.2.1/32 any  
        30 permit ip 192.168.3.3/32 any  
        40 deny any any
```

The task is to make a dict with access list number as key and access list rule number as value.

```
acl_dict = {'100' : '10', '100' : '20','200': '10', '200': '20', '200': '30', '200': '40'}
```

I have written a regex:

```
rx = re.compile("""
                   list\s(.*)[\n\r]
                   \s{4}(\d{1,3}).+$
                 """,re.MULTILINE|re.VERBOSE)
         for match in rx.finditer(text):
             print (match.group(1))
             print (match.group(2))
```

But is shows only number from first two strings (100 and 10)
I need to modify somehow regex to match all numbers to make needed dict.
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do it with a single method by using the newest *regex* module:

```
import regex

text = """
IP access list 100  
    10 permit igmp any any  
    20 deny any any  
IP access list 200  
    10 permit ip 192.168.1.1/32   
    20 permit ip 192.168.2.1/32 any  
    30 permit ip 192.168.3.3/32 any  
    40 deny any any
"""

acl_dict = {}
rx = regex.compile("list\s(.+)[\n\r](\s{4}(\d{1,3}).+[\n\r])*", regex.MULTILINE|regex.VERBOSE)
for match in rx.finditer(text):
    acl_dict[match.group(1)] = match.captures(3)

print(acl_dict)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 match.py 
{'200  ': ['10', '20', '30', '40'], '100  ': ['10', '20']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may extract full blocks first, and then get the leading  numbers from the inner parts (that can be *captured*).

Use

```
r'(?sm)IP access list\s+(\d+)(.*?)(?=^IP access list|\Z)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UFcboJ/1).

**Details**:

- `(?sm)` - enable the DOTALL and MULTILINE modes
- `IP access list`  - a literal string `IP access list` (can be prepended with `^`  if it is always at the line start)
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first...
- `(?=^IP access list|\Z)` - `IP access list` at the start of a line or end of string (`\Z`).

[Python sample code](http://ideone.com/kX2azE):

```
import re
input_str = "IP access list 100  \n        10 permit igmp any any  \n        20 deny any any  \nIP access list 200  \n        10 permit ip 192.168.1.1/32   \n        20 permit ip 192.168.2.1/32 any  \n        30 permit ip 192.168.3.3/32 any  \n        40 deny any any"
results = {}
for match in re.finditer(r"(?sm)IP access list\s+(\d+)(.*?)(?=^IP access list|\Z)", input_str):
    fields = re.findall(r"(?m)^\s*(\d+)", match.group(2))
    results[match.group(1)] = fields
print(results) # => {'200': ['10', '20', '30', '40'], '100': ['10', '20']}
```